# PyArg_ParseTuple() on arbitrary tuples

Tags: python-c-api

I am looking for confirmation on this issue:

Can I use PyArg_ParseTuple() on any Python tuple, or just on those passed as argument lists from function calls?

I see strong indication for the former, but to my reading the documentation is rather vague on this point, hence my question here.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that the error messages, if an error occurs while parsing the tuple, will be appropriate to a function call.

Otherwise, it should work on arbitrary tuples just as well as on argument lists.