# Call function from python with tuple return in c

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to call a python function from my C script. I success to return a double variable from the python function and print it in my C script. The problem I have now is that I need to return multiple variables (tuple) from python. How can I success that? My code with a single variable return is as follows:

```
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

int main(){
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc;
PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;   
int i;
double read;

Py_Initialize();
PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path");
PyList_Append(sysPath, PyString_FromString("."));
pName = PyString_FromString("eadata"); //Primer posible error
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);       

if(pModule != NULL){
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"lectura");
    if(pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)){
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,NULL);
        if(pValue != NULL){
            printf("Result of call: %lf \n", PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue));
            Py_DECREF(pValue);
        }
        else{
            Py_DECREF(pFunc);
            Py_DECREF(pModule);
            PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }       
}
else{
    PyErr_Print();
    fprintf(stderr, "Error al cargar eadata.py \n");
    }
}
```

My python script is:

```
def lectura():

    device = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
    baudrate = 115200   
    mt=mtdevice1.MTDevice(device, baudrate)

    ax=mtdevice1.acx 
    ay=mtdevice1.acy
    az=mtdevice1.acz

    wx=mtdevice1.wx             
    wy=mtdevice1.wy
    wz=mtdevice1.wz

    mx=mtdevice1.mx
    my=mtdevice1.my
    mz=mtdevice1.mz

    roll = mtdevice1.roll
    pitch = mtdevice1.pitch
    yaw = mtdevice1.yaw
    pc = mtdevice1.pc

    return ax
```

This works, but I want to return other variables at the same time such as ay,az, and so on. Is my first time using embedded python and I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps _[this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13942236/645128)_ will provide a clue?

Comment: Or _[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929920/how-to-pass-a-list-array-of-structs-from-python-to-c)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With a small caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200484/pyarg-parsetuple-on-arbitrary-tuples), you can use [`PyArg_ParseTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple) to take apart the tuple returned by the function you call.

This will work fine as long as the returned tuple matches the format string you provide to `PyArg_ParseTuple`. If there is a mismatch, the error produced by `PyArg_ParseTuple` will be misleading because it assumes that the tuple is an argument tuple.

A less convenient but more general approach is to use the [tuple API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html).

Comment: Yes. This works for me. I use the general approach tuple API. Thanks. @rici